# OkHttp not posting to mysql

Tags: java, php, android, okhttp

I have a problem here ..My app is supposed to send 3 values to the database, from text box etName,etEmailand etPassword

but instead, it is not send anything ...I'm new in android and I don't know some of the things I wrote in my code as I am   following some tutorials

this in my code for register

```
package com.xulucreatives.taxisiyaya;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText etName,etEmail,etPassword;
Button btnReg;

final String url_Register ="http://taxinote.000webhostapp.com/register_user.php";
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        etName = findViewById(R.id.RM);
        etEmail = findViewById(R.id.et_email);
        etPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_password);
        btnReg = findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);

        btnReg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                String Name = etName.getText().toString();
                String Email = etEmail.getText().toString();
                String Password = etPassword.getText().toString();

                new RegisterUser().execute(Name,Email,Password);
               // Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Im working you bitch",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
    public class RegisterUser extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String Name = strings[0];
            String Email = strings[1];
            String Password = strings[2];
            String finalURL = url_Register + "?user_name" + Name +
                    "&user_id"+ Email +
                    "&user_password"+ Password;

            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(finalURL)

                    .build();

            Response response = null;

            try{
                response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute();

                if(response.isSuccessful())

                {
                    String result = response.body().string();
                    if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("uaser registered successfully"))
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Registered Successfully",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                        finish();
                    }
                    else if(result.equalsIgnoreCase("user already exists")){

                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"User Already Exists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Ooops ! Ran into a problem , try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else{
                    Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"response not successful!! :/",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return null;
        }
    }
    public void showToast(final String Text){
        this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,Text,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

user_name, user_id and user_password are  from my php file in the server

```
<?php
require_once('connect.php');

$userName = $_GET['user_name'];
$userID = $_GET['user_id'];
$userPassword = $_GET['user_password'];


    $query = "select * from users where email = '$userID'";
    $recordExists = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conn, $query));

    if(isset($recordExists)){
        echo 'User already exists';

    }else{
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (name, email, password) VALUES ('$userName', '$userID', '$userPassword')";

        if(mysqli_query($conn, $query)){

            echo 'User registered successfully';

        }else{
            echo 'oops! please try again!';
        }
    }

?>
```

but its not working i dont know why

Comment: Do not use direct values from $_GET into an INSERT statement to the DB. Otherwise, you'll be open for SQLInjection.

Comment: About how to use OkHttp in Java, take a look at the examples from the official website: https://square.github.io/okhttp/

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an invalid url
which is

```
 String finalURL = url_Register + "?user_name" + Name +
                "&user_id"+ Email +
                "&user_password"+ Password;
```

and should be like this

```
 String finalURL = url_Register + "?user_name=" + Name +
                "&user_id="+ Email +
                "&user_password="+ Password;
```